# Trigger that sends email on Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a trigger that sends an email ONLY when there's an insert. I currently get an email whether there's an insert or not and I WANT to get an email ONLY when there's an insert in the table. Here's how the trigger currently looks like

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[myTriggerName]
 ON [dbo].[myTableName]
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
      @recipients = 'MyRecipients',  
      @profile_name = 'DBAdmins',  
      @subject = 'MySubject',   
      @body = 'Body';  

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Treating your question as academic, check the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables in the trigger.   If there are rows in `inserted` and none in `deleted` then it was an insert.

Comment: how do i script it so that it only checks for rows in the inserted table?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted`.   Google `SQL Server Trigger Tutorial` for plenty of examples.

Comment: i tried that but it says invalid objected name 'inserted'. Please if you have the time can you send me an example of  how the script should look like?

Comment: Can you add the script that is giving the invalid object name error to your original question?   Perhaps we can debug it.